# STM32L432KC: How to enable the ADC?

Tags: stm32, embedded

I am trying to get the ADC working. I tried following the tutorials, it seems I am doing it right but when I try to poll for the ADCAL bit from 1 > 0 It seems to never change. Whats going on here?

Essentially after writing `(1<<31)` I poll for that bit to change back to a zero. I know what the resulting register hex value is "`0x90000000`" with the `(1<<31)`. In the `while` loop if it changes it back to a zero the loop should result to a `false` and break out of it?
Not sure whats happening exactly.

[image]

Code w/ Comments:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stdio.h"
int msTicks = 0;
void ADC1_IRQHandler(void){



}

void delayMs(int ms){
    msTicks = 0;
    while (msTicks < ms);
}

void SysTick_Handler(void){
    msTicks++;
}
int main(void)
{
    SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= ((1<<13) | (1<<0)); //Enable ADC & GPIOA Clocks
    ADC1->CR &= ~(1<<29); //Disable Deep Sleep Mode
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<28); //Enable ADC Voltage Regulator
    delayMs(1000); //Give it 1 Second for the ADC Voltage Regulator to stabilize
    ADC1->IER = ((1<<0) | (1<<2)); //Enable EOC and ADRDY flags
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(ADC1_IRQn); //Enable the IRQ handler
    NVIC_SetPriority(ADC1_IRQn,0); //Set the priority of the IRQ handler
    ADC1->CFGR |= (1<<13); // Enable continuous mode
    ADC1->SQR1 |= ((1<<9) | (1<<8)); // Let the first sequence be Channel 12
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<31); //Start ADC Calibration
    while((ADC1->CR) == 0x90000000){ //Wait for Calibration to be done

    }
    ADC1->ISR |= (1<<0); //Clear the ADRDY flag
    ADC1->CR |= (1<<0); //Enable ADC


  while (1)
  {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not selected any clock source for ADC with the RCC_CCPIR register bits ADCSEL[1:0].

Comment: Thank you! That did it